# Filter table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello so currently I have this table filter code which you can try on [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vwhccu7w/4/) fiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Document</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <script src="../js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
      <script>
         (function(document) {
          'use strict';

          var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

              var _input;

              function _onInputEvent(e) {
                  _input = e.target;
                  var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
                  Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
                      Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                          Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
                      });
                  });
              }

              function _filter(row) {
                  var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(),
                      val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
                  row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
              }

              return {
                  init: function() {
                      var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
                      Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                          input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
                      });
                  }
              };
          })(Array.prototype);

          document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
              if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                  LightTableFilter.init();
              }
          });

         })(document);


         $(document).ready(function() {
         $('a').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var text = $(this).text();
          $('input[type=search]').val(text);
          $( "#right-label" ).focus();
         });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      Search: <input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="order-table" id="right-label" placeholder="Filter"> 
      <a href="#">Active</a> | <a href="#">Inactive</a> | <a href="#">Banned</a>
      <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact Number</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Robert</td>
            <td>09054848</td>
            <td>BSIT</td>
            <td>Active</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>5959547</td>
            <td>BSA</td>
            <td>Inactive</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>5959547</td>
            <td>BSA</td>
            <td>Banned</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

The table filter is working but I want to add text/s that when I click on it, it will be the value of the textbox and will filter the table. The text/s I added is Active, Inactive and Banned. If you click one of it, it will be the value of the input. The problem is the filter code isn't working with that code.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Might be a DOM bind problem, where you need to bind the element using `.on()` https://api.jquery.com/on/ instead of `.click()`

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: Why are you using element linking in stead of ID linking, if you add an extra table or extra links your setup won't work. 

I also see the _onInputEvent (I don't know the componetn but is it possible this fires onkeydown?)

Comment: @FewFlyBy No but if you provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) ill give it a go

Comment: @PieterSchool Yes that's the thing I guess, that it fires onkeydown that's why just clicking won't work

Comment: @gerdi https://jsfiddle.net/vwhccu7w/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the code check it out
https://jsfiddle.net/kushal812/vwhccu7w/16/

Some of the changes made

```
var table = $('#mytable')
$('a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var text = $(this).text() || "";
     table.find('tbody > tr').hide();
     $('input[type=search]').val(text);
     table.find("." + text.toLowerCase()).removeClass("hidden")
 });
```

Comment: Hello it works but when you clear the textbox and start clicking on links again, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: There is a small glitch in your code. The links (active, inactive, banned) work the first time. but if you use them and then change or empty the text in the textbox and then try to use them again, it doesent update.

Also the headers disappear when filtering.

Comment: Use: table.find('tbody > tr').hide(); in stead of table.find('tr').hide();

Comment: @PieterSchool where is the table.find('tr').hide(); code? I can only see table.find("tr").addClass("hidden")

Comment: @FewFlyBy I meant that one :) my bad

Comment: Hello I have added class to a tr and added ID on every href and when I click on a link it will hide a tr element. Check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwhccu7w/15/). If you have better suggestions please comment

Comment: @Kushal This is cleanier. Post it as your own answer so I can vote it as best answer ;) Thanks!

Comment: @Kushal hey just a follow up, what if I will add Show all button/link?

Comment: @FewFlyBy yes you can add it .. just make the value of your search box blank .. it should work